# cannot load stylus in slim template

Tags: slim-lang, tilt

when I am trying to use the styl: tag in the stylus file I am not able to compile it...here is the error I am getting.

```
Temple::FilterError: Tilt engine styl is not available.
  Use --trace for backtrace.
```

Comment: What's the output of the `--trace` command? I think the error is clear: you are not including the basic `Tilt engine`.. Take a look at `https://github.com/slim-template/slim` under the `Embedded engines (Markdown, ...)` section.

Comment: It has to be something like `Slim::Embedded.default_options[:styl] = {}`

Comment: where do you need to put the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the patch to tilt registeration.

```
  require 'stylus/tilt/stylus'
  register StylusTemplate, 'stylus'
```